# Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'model' parameter a non-null default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create Multilanguage web site with ASP.NET core MVC
I created My DTO class in this way

```
public class RegisterUserDto
{
    private readonly LanguageService _languageService;
    public RegisterUserDto()
    {
        
    }
    public RegisterUserDto(LanguageService languageService)
    {
        _languageService = languageService;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ConfirmPassword")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Compare("Password" , ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string GetNameDisplayName()
    {
        return _languageService.Getkey("RegisterName");
    }
    public string GetEmailDisplayName()
    {
        return _languageService.Getkey("Email");
    }
    public string GetPasswordDisplayName()
    {
        return _languageService.Getkey("Password");
    }
    public string GetConfirmPasswordDisplayName()
    {
        return _languageService.Getkey("ConfirmPassword");
    }

}
```

Because I want to show Name of elements based on current language I Implement my DTO class in this way . It works fine in any .cshtml files , however when I want to Post data in a form it shows error

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894772/error-in-form-post-model-bound-complex-types-must-not-be-abstract-or-value-type)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'CMS.Core.Models.DTO.RegisterUserDto'. Model bound complex
> types must not be abstract or value types and must have a
> parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary
> constructor. Alternatively, give the 'model' parameter a non-null
> default value.

here is my controller class

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterUserDto model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    return View();
}
```

I have already seen these posts but It doesn't work

[stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894772/error-in-form-post-model-bound-complex-types-must-not-be-abstract-or-value-type)

[Stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976384/model-bound-complex-types-must-not-be-abstract-or-value-types-and-must-have-a-pa)

[stackoverflow3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237069/model-bound-complex-types-must-not-be-abstract-or-value-types-and-must-have-a-pa)

Thank you in advance for your support. I truly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Since your model is a class, not a record, It seems that this specific part of the exception message isn't relevant to your problem. What happens if you remove the `RegisterUserDto(LanguageService languageService)` constructor from your type (and inject the language service via a method or property instead)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled
thank you . it works

Comment: Really? It was actually a shot in the dark, I'm kind off surprised it did, since your class already has a parameterless constructor.  perhaps it's a problem with the error message (meaning it should note that you can only have a single, parameterless constructor) or something like that. I usually don't work with asp.net so I'm no expert